# Concatenating two time Series with same date but getting two different rows for each date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, concatenation

I have two DataFrames

DataFrame 1(df1):

```
Date    Open    High    Low Close   Adj Close   Volume
2008-01-01  6136.75 6165.35 6109.85 6144.35 6144.35 0
2008-01-02  6144.70 6197.0  6060.85 6179.39 6179.39 0
2008-01-03  6184.25 6230.14 6126.39 6178.54 6178.54 0
```

DataFrame 2(df2):

```
time       open     high    low      close     Volume   Volume MA
1344570300  16.33   16.51   16.03   16.07      NaN      NaN
1344829500  16.07   16.65   16      16.01      NaN      NaN
1344915900  16.01   16.15   15.57   15.64      NaN      NaN
1345088700  15.64   16.12   15.07   15.69      NaN      NaN
```

I am trying to concat two time-series together on their date columns.
The date column in the one-time series is Unix time.
The date column in the second time series is 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import time

# read in the data
df1 = pd.read_csv('/content/NSE_INDIAVIX, 1D.csv').reset_index()
df2 = pd.read_csv('/content/nsei.csv')

# convert the date columns from unix time to YYYY-MM-DD:
df1['Date'] = df1['time'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0, join='outer', ignore_index=False,
          keys=None, levels=None, names=None, verify_integrity=False,
          copy=True)
#sort the dataframe by date
df.sort_values(by='Date', inplace=True)
```

The output that I am getting is :

```
df[['open','high','low','Date']][2000:2005]
```

```
         open       high          low         Date
1561    7428.75   7504.00     7269.04     2014-05-26
439       19.84     21.41       17.77     2014-05-27
1562    7363.10   7372.95     7274.75     2014-05-27
440       19.10     19.55       17.33     2014-05-28
1563    7324.95   7344.75     7302.60     2014-05-28
```

Though the Dates are the same I am getting *two different rows* for the same date instead of *merging* them together.

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: dates in `df2` don't seem to match the dates in `df1`...

Comment: You're concatenating the dataframes, while you actually want to [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) them.